# Нужно ли тире между словом "сегодня" и названием дня недели?

Tags: пунктуация

Хочу расставить правильно знаки препинания в следующем предложении: "Лишь вечером я понял, что сегодня понедельник". Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить тире после слова "сегодня"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире не требуется, но поставить можно – для акцентирования.